# How can I hide (make invisible) row in JTable?

Tags: java, jtable, row

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The <s>best</s> easiest way would be to remove the corresponding element from the model.

Comment: Finally I did this way... Two dataSets... One is full, the other one populates when fireDataTableChanged called... But I'm afraid it's slow...

Comment: Removing a row in a view should not affect the model. And @willcodejavaforfood, how do you suppose to add that data again to the model? It's supposed you are interacting with the view to hide a row. You must not know anything about its data or its contents... removing data from the model should be trivial that will be removed from its view.

Answer (score 16):

There is the `RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object>` class you can use to filter out rows. The DefaultTableModel can be replaced by your own model. To filter, implement the method

```
@Override
public boolean include(Entry entry) {
    // All rows are included if no filter is set
    if (filterText.isEmpty())
        return true;

    // If any of the column values contains the filter text,
    // the row can be shown
    for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValueCount(); i++) {
        String value = entry.getStringValue(i);
        if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) != -1)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When accessing rows, for instance listening to ListSelectionEvents, do not forget to translate the visible row index to the complete row index in your model. Java provides a function for this as well:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

    int visibleRowIndex = ... // Get the index of the selected row

    // Convert from the selection index based on the visible items to the
    // internal index for all elements.
    int internalRowIndex = tableTexts
            .convertRowIndexToModel(visibleRowIndex);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Sun's Tutorial for JTables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and look at the Sorting and Filtering section.

Comment: I'm mistaken or filtering was enabled only in Java 1.6?

Comment: JXTable from swinglabs if you want to try filtering in <1.6. You can also make your own TableModel that decorates another TableModel with sorting functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a arraylists for each column that are populated by values filtered for and implement these in a custom renderer.  If a cells entire row values are not met the renderer recursively calls itself with row+1.

if the cells row does meet criteria, it gets rendered, another arraylist stores the row numbers already rendered, its best explained by example this method is in customer renderer extends JLabel

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object color,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    Object value;
    String s;

    try {
        if (row == 0) {
            drawn[column].clear();
        }// drawn is arraylist which stores cols rend
        if (row > table.getModel().getDataVector.size()) {
            return null;
        }// if we go too far
        if (drawn[column].contains(Integer.toString(row)) == true) {
            // already rendered?
            return getTableCellRendererComponent(table, color, isSelected,
                    hasFocus, (row + 1), column);
        }// render row+1

        for (int i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
            value = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, i);
            s = (i == 1) ? df.format(value) : value.toString();
            if (filters[i].contains(s) != true) {
                //try and put in next row, if succeeds when it reaches column 8 it adds row to
                return getTableCellRendererComponent(table, color,
                        isSelected, hasFocus, (row + 1), column);
            }
        }

        value = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);

        setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));

        if ((isSelected == false)) {

            if ((column == 1)) {
                setForeground(Color.magenta);
            }// just formatting
            else {
                setForeground(Color.black);
                setBackground(Color.white);
            }

        } else {
            setBackground(Color.blue);
            setForeground(Color.white);
        }

        if ((column == 1))// col 1 is a date, other columns strings
        {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : df.format(value));
        } else {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        }

        todayStr = df.format(new java.util.Date());
        dateval = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
        String datevalStr = df.format(dateval);
        if (datevalStr.equals(todayStr)) {
            setForeground(Color.red);
        }
        drawn[column].add(Integer.toString(row));// mark row as rendered

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
    return this;
}
```